# How to stop background shaking when document.addEventListener('scroll') is present

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
    // Make BG not scroll with the window
    let e = document.querySelector('body .bg-img');
    let topValue = scrollY*0.5;
    e.style.top = `${topValue}px`;
});
```

When i try to scroll, the background shakes up and dow like crazy. I've looked on the internet and it seems like it it hasn't got the answer. I think it can have something to do that it goes really slow to do the calculations, am I on the right path, and in that case, how do I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that JavaScript is the right answer for this?  Seems like a CSS solution should be simple to implement and it wouldn't have the weird artifact of needing to update with every scroll event...

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @AlexanderNied How would you do that?

Comment: Have you tried using [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) or [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) combined with `top:0` for your `.bg-img` element? Maybe futz with that `top` value since I see you've got some math you're applying-- you could also use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for the value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not a correct way of doing this. You should use CSS instead:

```
body {
  background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking for. The background just hides with the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `.bg-top` background element to not scroll with the window, you should use the css property `position: fixed` instead.

Run the **Code Snippet** below to see how it works:

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.bg-img{
  background: url("//picsum.photos/200/100");height: 100px;width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
</p>
```

---

But if you **HAVE TO** use JavaScript for whatever reason, you can change the `position` property value on scroll and assign the `top` property to `0`.

Run the **Code Snippet** below to see how it works:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    // Make BG not scroll with the window
    let e = document.querySelector('body .bg-img');
    e.style.position = "fixed";
    e.style.top = "0";
});
```

```css
html, body {padding: 0; width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; height: 100%;}
.bg-img{background:url("//picsum.photos/200/100");height: 100px; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ab aut placeat eligendi ducimus doloremque fugit dolore esse, quis reprehenderit quod dignissimos similique, autem tempora nihil, aliquam eius. Dolores, repellendus!
</p>
```